# sync google contact on gnome contacts

Tags: 14.04, unity

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity and I'd like to sync my contacts from Google on Gnome contacts without to pass via Evolution.

I've tested it on Gnome Shell 3.14 and it run perfectly while on unity no.

Why? is there a app that I've to install on Ubuntu 14.04 Unity?

thanks in advance.

Comment: someone can say me why on unity while gnome shell is possible to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved that in this way

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what you did?